# should pythonpath have directories specific to python2 and python3?

Tags: python, python-2.x, pythonpath

I am working with both python 2 and python 3 on a daily basis.
Should I be adding paths to PYTHONPATH that are specific to a python version, like the following, which is specific to python 2?

```
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
```

If the answer is **yes**, then would python 3 know not to use these modules?

If the answer is **no**, then where should I add the above path if not to PYTHONPATH?

Comment: I suggest you to user virtualenv and virtualenvwrapper  instead of changing PYTHONPATH manuallly

Answer (score 2):

Python 3 will attempt to load modules from your PYTHONPATH and fail. A possible solution to this is the following.

Set your PYTHONPATH to

```
/usr/local/lib/%PYTHON%/dist-packages
```

and create a file *sitecustomize.py* in the directory returned by

```
python -c "import site ; print site.getsitepackages()"
```

with the following content:

```
import sys
from distutils.sysconfig import get_python_version

sys.path = [x.replace('%PYTHON%', 'python{}'.format(get_python_version()))
            for x in sys.path]
```

This will replace the relevant part of the directory name with whatever python version is executed.

Comment: Use parenthesis around the print function for Python 3 `python -c "import site ; print(site.getsitepackages())"`